# android softkeyboard not closed after clear the task

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

In my application i have one edittext with one image for add the task into database.My problem is when i add the task in database after that the android soft keyboard visible instead of closing.I am using all those examples in stack overflow but not getting result please any one help me...

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextselector"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/addtask"
    android:hint="AddTask"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />
```

MyOnRightdrawable listener:

```
    edittextAddTask.setOnTouchListener(new RightDrawableOnTouchListener(
                edittextAddTask) {        
            @Override
             boolean onDrawableTouch(MotionEvent event) {
//Add the task in db.


    //I am using this code but not working for me
    /*InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                   mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittextAddTask.getWindowToken(), 0);*/
    }
```

My Screenshot for edittext:

[image]

Comment: try to hide the keyboard on click event of add button after inserted data in database

Comment: i am not using onclick event using only onDrawableTouch listener only...

Comment: Ok...so u r implementing your code in fragment or in Activity?

Comment: i am implement in fragment

Answer (score 0):

try to move focus to any other view.

after that close the keyboard

Comment: i am not understanding please give brief

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,  int count) {


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittextAddTask.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
});
```